# How to determine Paypal signature credential in new Paypal API

Tags: paypal

According to [Paypal Developer Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/).

For example, an Express Checkout call requires the following input fields:

- USER - The API User name credential.
- PWD - The API Password credential.
- SIGNATURE - The Signature credential.

---

But in new paypal developer application, it only shows endpoint, client ID and secret, there is no API credential. How to get it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to select the account you are wanting credentials for and click on the profile link.  Then when the pop up comes up, you can click the tab for "API Credentials".  IF you do not see these credentials/tab, then you would need to log into the actual test sandbox seller account and navigate to your profile and actual request the credentials.